# can not use navagation properties in web grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

in web-grid i can not use navigation properties between my classes(products and productimages classes). for example i have used below code in web grid:

```
  grid.Column("", "test",item=> (item.ProductImages.First().Id)+(item.Price))
```

but i got error:

```
  'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<WebStore.Models.ProductImage>' does not contain a definition for 'First'
```

my total code is like below:

```
    @model IEnumerable<WebStore.Models.Product>
```

@using System.Linq;

```
   @{
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, rowsPerPage: 5,ajaxUpdateContainerId:"divGrid");

}

     @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "gridStyle", headerStyle: "gridHeader", rowStyle: "gridRow", alternatingRowStyle: null,htmlAttributes:new{Id="divGrid"},
    columns: new WebGridColumn[] {
   grid.Column("ProductName", "Product Name"),
   grid.Column("Price", "Price"),
   grid.Column("Description", "Description"),
    grid.Column("CategoryName","Category Name",x=>x.Category.CategoryName),

  grid.Column("", "test",item=> (item.ProductImages.First().Id)+(item.Price)),



  grid.Column("","",x=>Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new{id=x.Id})),
  grid.Column("","",x=>Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new{id=x.Id})),
 grid.Column("","",x=>Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new{id=x.Id}))
}
                    )
```

this is my index view:

```
 @model IEnumerable<WebStore.Models.Product>
  @using System.Linq
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutCategory.cshtml";
}

<br/>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

<div id="divGrid">

@{ Html.RenderPartial("_ProductTitle", Model); }
</div>
```

this is my RenderPartial that use web grid before i posted:

```
    @model IEnumerable<WebStore.Models.Product>
    @using System.Linq


 @ViewBag.test
 @{
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, rowsPerPage: 5,ajaxUpdateContainerId:"divGrid");

}

  @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "gridStyle", headerStyle: "gridHeader", rowStyle: "gridRow", alternatingRowStyle: null,htmlAttributes:new{Id="divGrid"},
   columns: new WebGridColumn[] {
  grid.Column("ProductName", "Product Name"),
  grid.Column("Price", "Price"),
  grid.Column("Description", "Description"),
  grid.Column("CategoryName","Category Name",x=>x.Category.CategoryName),


 grid.Column("", "test",item=>(int) (item.ProductImages.FirstOrDefault().Id)+(int)(item.Price)),




  grid.Column("","",x=>Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new{id=x.Id})),
  grid.Column("","",x=>Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new{id=x.Id})),
  grid.Column("","",x=>Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new{id=x.Id}))
 }
                    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer of my question with below code from the net:

I followed your steps and test your code and the same error display. So I think the format in your code can not be used in webgrid. So I think about another way to meet your requirement: we need a ViewModel to display what you want to show in the View and search the first item in Controller then save as ViewModel and pass the ViewModel to View, then we do not need search in the View. Here I will show you the steps with my demo.

1. Now, we have two model Product and Quantity that one product has many quantities. We should create a ViewModel.

ViewModel.cs:

```
 public class ViewModel
  {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public long quan { get; set; }
  }
```

2. We can initialize some data and search the first value of Quantity depend on Product in Controller and assign to the ViewModel.

InventoryController .cs:

```
    public class InventoryController : Controller
    public ActionResult WebgridSample()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Product> inventoryList =
            new ObservableCollection<Product>();
        inventoryList.Add(new Product
        {
            Id = "P101",
            Name = "Computer",
            Description = "All type of computers",
            quantity = new List<Quantity>
            {
                new Quantity {QUAN = 100 },
                new Quantity {QUAN = 200 },
                new Quantity {QUAN = 300 }
            }
        });
        inventoryList.Add(new Product
        {
            Id = "P102",
            Name = "Laptop",
            Description = "All models of Laptops",

            quantity = new List<Quantity>
            {
                new Quantity {QUAN = 400 },
                new Quantity {QUAN = 500 },
                new Quantity {QUAN = 600 }
            },
        });
        inventoryList.Add(new Product
        {
            Id = "P103",
            Name = "Camera",
            Description = "Hd  cameras",
            quantity = new List<Quantity>
            {
                new Quantity {QUAN = 700 },
                new Quantity {QUAN = 800 },
                new Quantity {QUAN = 900 }
            }
        });
        IEnumerable<string> model = (from sig in inventoryList
                                    select new ViewModel
                     {
                         Name = sig.Name,
                         Description = sig.Description,
                         quan = sig.quantity.FirstOrDefault(),
                     }).ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
```

3. We can call each parameters of ViewModel in webgrid without using First().

WebgridSample.cshtml:

```
   <div id="gridContent">
    @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
        headerStyle: "header",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
        selectedRowStyle: "select",
        columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("Id", ),
        grid.Column("Name", " Name"),
        grid.Column("Description", "Description", style: "description"),
        grid.Column("Quantity", "quan "</i>)
 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because definition of `First` is available in `System.Linq`. So, you should have System.Linq in your razor page :

```
@using System.Linq;
```

if you are using Linq in multiple page, you can add `System.Linq` namespace in web.config so that you do not need to write above using in each page. You can add namespace in web.config in following configuration :

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
        <pages>
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System.Linq" />
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
    </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: I have used @using.system.linq in this page but does not work

Comment: I am not sure, what have you done wrong but using  System.Linq should bring all definition for Linq methods.

Comment: no, actually i do not know how and where i have to use that

Comment: You should add reference System.Core dll in your references if it's not already referenced.

Comment: Can you pleasepost your full razor view source?

Comment: Okey, I posted razor view

Comment: You have firstordefault method now in your razor. Which exception is it throwing now?

Comment: Same before, does not contain a definition for firstordefault

Comment: Have you able to fix issue?

Comment: No i could not fix the problem, also i asked of my teachers, he told linq does not work easily in web grid and i have to make view model of product class and string ... or using table my self and do not using web grid, any way if you find a way please send to me.

Comment: I have no experience with webgrid so no idea about this issue. But you can still try with creating html helper which take your item and gives first image id. Then, you call that helper from your razor page

Comment: my problem fixed you can check the answer https://forums.asp.net/t/2115995.aspx?can+not+use+navagation+properties+in+web+grid